# Can't search for a specific record in database

Tags: php, html, search, phpmyadmin

I want to search for a specific record in database and show it on html page. I have inserted a search bar with a search button. I want to enter let's say Student Name and view the record of that student in an html table. But it's not working, It shows nothing in the table. Here is the code for search:

```html
<?php
include("connection.php");
if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
 $valueToSearch=$_POST['valueToSearch'];
 $query="SELECT * FROM 'table_name' WHERE Student_Name LIKE '%".$valueToSearch."%";
 $search_result=filterTable($query);

}
else{
 $query="SELECT * FROM 'table_name'";
 $search_result=filterTable($query);
}
function filterTable($query)
{
 $connect=@mysql_connect("localhost","root","","db");
 $filter_Result=@mysql_query($connect,$query);
 return $filter_Result;
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Search Record</title>
 <style>
 table,tr,th,td
 {
  border:1px solid black;
 }
</style>
</head>
<body>
 <form action="search.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="valueToSearch" placeholder="ValueToSearch"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" name="search" value="Filter"><br><br>
  <table>
     <tr>
                    <th>Id</th>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                    <th>Age</th>
                </tr>
                <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($search_result)):?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $row['id'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['fname'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['lname'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['age'];?></td>
                </tr>
                <?php endwhile;?>
            </table>
        </form>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `<form action="search.php" method="post">` AND `isset($_POST['search']` ?

Comment: `phpmyadmin` is not a database, it is just an web interface that provides you access to your databases and its tables. Alternatives are `adminer` and stand alone applications `DBeaver` , `MySQL Workbench` `HeidiSQL` and many more...

Comment: Maybe you're missing a single quote `'` after the last `%` in your query? For testing, I'd also recommend letting php show errors for easier debugging: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5438060/showing-all-errors-and-warnings

Comment: Downvote for using MySQL extension with error suppression.

Answer (score 0):

escape your keywords with  `mysql_escape_string();`, like second thing don,t use `mysql*` use `mysqli` or `pdo` because `mysql*` has been removed from `php 7.*`

```
$valueToSearch= mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$_POST['valueToSearch']);
```

after that use this query

```
$query="SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE Student_Name LIKE '%$valueToSearch%'";
```

because you have syntax error if you echo it you need to get like this

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE Student_Name LIKE 'something';
```

i am giving you example with `mysqli` paste it in `connection.php`

```
$connect=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","db");
```

now your code should be

```
include("connection.php");
if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
    $valueToSearch= mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$_POST['valueToSearch']);
    $query="SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE Student_Name LIKE '%$valueToSearch%'";
    $search_result=filterTable($query,$connect);

}
else{
    $query="SELECT * FROM table_name";
    $search_result=filterTable($query,$connect);
}
function filterTable($query,$connect)
{

    $filter_Result=mysqli_query($connect,$query);
    if (!$filter_Result) {
        die('query is not valid '.mysqli_error($connect));
    }
    else{
        return $filter_Result;
    }

}
```

Comment: why are you using function

Comment: To run the query

Comment: you need to remove mysql use mysqli or pdo

Comment: I assume connection is not established in connection.php but in the function below..

Comment: how can you assume like that

Comment: Because he is establishing the connection in the function `filterTable()`

Comment: he is establishing  the connection in the function because that is not accessible in function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167234/discussion-between-rahul-shrivastava-and-yuri).

Comment: It shows undefined variable connect and query is not valid

Comment: why the query is not valid

Comment: $connect=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","db"); paste it in connection.php

Comment: I have resolved it but now it's showing query is not valid

Comment: $query="SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE Student_Name LIKE '%$valueToSearch%'"; try it

Answer (score 0):

Forget any `mysql_` feature. You are establishing connection to database with `mysql` but trying to read results with `mysqli_`.. Try with

```
<?php
include("connection.php");
if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
    $valueToSearch=$_POST['valueToSearch'];
    $query="SELECT * FROM 'table_name' WHERE Student_Name LIKE '%".$valueToSearch."%'";

    $search_result=filterTable($query);

}
else{
    $query="SELECT * FROM 'table_name'";
    $search_result=filterTable($query);
}
function filterTable($query) {
    $connection = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "","db");
    $filter_Result = $connection->query($query)
    return !$filter_Result ? null : $filter_Result;
}
?>
```

Then, down in your form, replace:

```
while ($row = $search_result->fetch_array()) {
    ...
    ...
}
```

Hint:

- Consider about moving your connection establishment from `filterTable()` function to the `connection.php` file and use `GLOBAL $connection;` in the function
- Moving your connection to that file will allow you to escape string at any time with `$myVar = $mysqli->real_escape_string( $myVar )` which will prevent injection